# Set Unicode text on MFC form controls in Multi-Byte Char Set application

Tags: c++, visual-c++, unicode, mfc

I have `Multi-Byte Char Set` `MFC` windows application. Now I need to display international single byte ASCI characters on windows controls. I can't use `ASCI` characters directly because to display them correctly it is required windows locale be set to adequate country. I need to display characters in all windows locale cases. For this purpose I must convert ASCI to unicode. I can display required international characters in `MessageBoxW`, but how to display them on windows MFC controls using  `SetWindowText`?

To show `unicode` string in `MessageBoxW` I construct it in `wstring`

```
WORD  g  [] = {0x105,0x106,0x107,0x108,0x109,0x110,0x111,0x112,0x113,0x114,0x115,0x116,0x117,0x118,0x119,0x120};
wstring gg (reinterpret_cast<wchar_t*>(g),15);
MessageBoxW(NULL, gg.c_str() , gg.c_str() , MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
```

Seting MFC form control text:

```
class MyFrm: public CDialogEx
{
virtual BOOL OnInitDialog();
}
...
BOOL MyFrm::OnInitDialog()
{
GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT_TICKET_NUMBER)->SetWindowText( ???);
}
```

Is it possible somehow convert `wstring gg` to CString and show unicode chars on window control?

Comment: Can you be more specific? So you want to set Unicode text into MFC control box while the project target Multi-Byte Char Set? Can you post the code snippet where you try it?

Comment: Also note that Unicode is being supported starting from Windows XP. You should use ASCII only if you are targeting an older OS which I don't think is the case.

Comment: Yes, I want to set Unicode text into MFC control box while the project target Multi-Byte Char Set. I have added some code in message body

Comment: The *proper* answer is to convert the entire project to Unicode, but I presume you didn't want to hear that.

Answer (score 2):

You could try casting your CDialogEx 'this' object to HWND and then call explictly Win32 API to set text using wchars. So your code will look something like this:

```
BOOL MyFrm::OnInitDialog()
{
SetDlgItemTextW((HWND)(*this), IDC_EDIT_TICKET_NUMBER, gg.c_str());
}
```

But as I mentioned earlier Unicode is supported starting from Windows XP and using ASCII is really not a good idea unless you're targeting those very very old OS'es before it. Using them nowdays will cause ALL ASCII strings you pass to be firstly converted into Unicode by the Win32 API. So it is a better idea to switch your project entirely to UNICODE.

Comment: I doubt that the performance difference is even measurable, but it's good advice nonetheless.

Comment: Using win32 API I got not expected chars, but some strange ones. But I found that I even can't type regional characters on this control - I'm getting the same strange ones. I thought that it is font problem, but changing font to Lucida Console (that notepad is using where I can type international characters) didn't changed situation.

Comment: So then better create a new question for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, note that you can simply directly initialize a `std::wstring` with your Unicode hex character data, without any ugly useless `reinterpret_cast<wchar_t*>`, etc.

Instead of this:

> ```
> WORD  g  [] = {0x105,0x106,0x107,0x108,...,0x120};
> wstring gg (reinterpret_cast<wchar_t*>(g),15);
> ```

just consider that:

```
wstring text = L"\x0105\x0106\x0108...\0x0120";
```

The latter seems much cleaner to me.

Second, if you want to pass an instance to `std::wstring` to an MFC method that expects a `const wchar_t*` input string pointer, just consider using **`wstring::c_str()`** method.

In addition, the best suggestion I can give you is to just port your app to **Unicode**.
ASCII/MBCS should be considered programming model of the past for MFC; they bring lots of problem when you want to write "international" code.